# MSTSC - mouse input works, but somehow keybord input is locked. How to unlock?

Tags: remote-desktop

MSTSC (Microsoft Terminal Services Client, aka Remote Desktop) - mouse input works, but somehow keyboard input is locked. (I see desktop and can use mouse with apps but can't input a single character.) (All I remember - I set down onto the keyboard.. so it must have been a shourt cut) How to unlock?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote Desktop Keyboard Doesn't Work](https://superuser.com/questions/732318/remote-desktop-keyboard-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 17):

Please go to:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use
```

Turn off *Filter keys* and check.

Comment: This resolved my problem with being unable to use my keyboard in a Windows Server 2012 remote desktop session. I must of somehow activated Filter Keys by mistake. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  Mine was already off.  I turned it on; saved it; turned it off and saved it back.

Comment: Sweet! Must remember though, it is turned on in your remote computer, not in your computer. I was turning on and off in mine... which ofcourse didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I assume your keyboard is working fine for a non-RDP window.

While the RDP window is active, tap each of the left *and* right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys. Also tap the Windows key, the Menu key (the other "new" key added for Windows) and any other modifier keys.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue. I rebooted the remote machine (a poor solution). That worked for me. Did not want to spend a lot of time in the net looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use

uncheck turn on mouse keys under control the mouse with the keyboard.