# Remote Desktop Keyboard Doesn't Work

Tags: windows

I was working in RDP the other night when my keyboard quit working.  I am not sure what I did, but I can't seem to get it working again.  The keyboard works fine when not in Remote Desktop.  Please help!

Answer (score 19):

**First:** Check your RDP-Session Options:
In Local Resources you have the ability to set Keyboard: On this Computer

**If that doesn't work:** Control Panel - All Items - Ease of Access Center - Make Keyboard easier to use and disable the Filter Keys (on the remote computer)...you may have accidentally set this with a key combination.

Comment: Filter Keys was pressed accidentally by user

Comment: This saved me smashing my keyboard :)

Answer (score 6):

I've found that often after an RDP session the local machine keyboard control goes haywire in Windows 7. Sometimes it stops working or the keys do funky things (such as typing a letter will minimize all screens instead of type the letter) happens on all of my Windows 7 machines too.

I've found to get things back I hit the "Windows" key to the left of the keyboard. It will open the Start menu but for some reason after that everything works again.

Comment: Were you using a different keyboard layout than standard Qwerty and then used Alt Tab?

Comment: _hit the "Windows" key to the left of the keyboard_ Wow, this actually worked. I had working keyboard within the RDP session but on the local Windows when typing a `|` it put a `<` instead. - I usually encounter a broken keyboard within RDP but working locally so this was a first.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multiple monitors, move the screen to the other monitor and try to type.

If you can, then move the screen back to the other monitor and you should still be able to type. I have no idea why it happens, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: This is very weird, but this works for me, i have two monitors and yes when i my keyboard is locked i just move the screen from one monitor to another and just like magic i am able to type again. And even more weird is the fact that this keep happening and the only solution is to switch the screen from one desktop to another.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem where the . , / and ~ keys ( possibly some others ) were not working under RDP.  After restarting the remote computer it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

In My case restarting host didn't work, but 1 of 2 things worked.
I logged in to host with same user locally and installed a hot fix.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/Hotfix/KbHotfix?kbnum=2579381&kbln=en-us

Comment: That link provides only a download and no explanation of the problem or the fix. Here is the link to corresponding support article: https://support.microsoft.com/eu-es/help/2579381/a-remote-desktop-session-does-not-respond-to-keyboard-input-or-mouse-i

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions worked for me, but [found this solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a371325-ba43-4768-ba6b-618517400946/remote-desktop-keyboard-quit-working-on-host-from-mac?forum=winRDc) which did the trick.

Solution: on Remote Desktop session go to **Window > User Name > Sing out** (log off the session instead of disconnecting to see how it works.)

At next sign-in the keyboard worked again.